# Is my symmetric encryption algorithm safe?

Tags: algorithm, encryption, encryption-symmetric, vigenere

I recently decided to write my own symmetric encryption program (which could be used in a custom password manager for example). 
I would like your opinion about him, did I make big mistakes? else would it be easily breakable?

It is basically a Vigenere fork trying to get closer to the principles of Vernam encryption but remaining easy to use (you can use any key in order to encrypt your text).

**How does it work?**

- You enter a message (e.g. hello world) and a seed (e.g. seed).
- The seed is transformed into a number thanks to a hash function
- We add the number of letters of the message to this number, and we hash it another time
- A pseudo-random number generator is initialized with the result and a list of random numbers of the text size is generated (it's the key).
- We shift each letter with the corresponding number in the list (the first letter of the message is shifted with the first number of our generated list)

  `Example :
  Alphabet: [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z]
  List : [1,18,3,17,0]
  Word: "hello"
  h+1 = j
  e+18 = w
  l+3 = o
  l+17=c  (as the alphabet is finished, we continue at the beginning)
  o+0=o
  Output: "jwoco"`

**The principles of Vernam encryption specifies that :**

- the key used to offset the letters must be at least as large as the text size -> It's okay
- The key must only be used once -> It's okay if you change your seed or the size of the message (since we include the text size in the hash used to initialize the key)
- The key must be completely random -> This will depend on the random number generation algorithm and the hash algorithm but if they are good we should have an output with which it is impossible without the key to find a text that is more likely than another to be the original message.

Is my explanation clear? Do you agree with me? Do you have any clarifications to add? improvements to propose or algorithms of random number generation and hash to advise me?

have a nice day,
Thomas!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about programming.  The most obvious place would be https://crypto.stackexchange.com, but [their on-topic guide](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says they won't take this question, either.

Comment: Hey ! This is a real programming problem since I am asking you which algorithm of hash and random number generation I should use, but to understand what my needs are I have to explain how the system works. If you want I can try to bring out of the topic this question?

Comment: This is not a programming question which is useful to publish. It does not even specify a programming ecosystem. It is rather theoritical about an algoritm, and you expect people here to dive into it. It helps no one, it proofs nothing.. I voted too to close it.

Comment: You've basically reinvented the stream cipher with a vigenere cipher instead of XOR. At the very least, you'll need a CPRNG and to change the seed of your RNG every time, or it's vulnerable to chosen plain-text attacks. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_cipher

Comment: Thank you very much user3080953 ! I was just looking at the Wikipedia page about CSPRN. I think that I'll use SHA-3 for the hash algrithm (I'm using Java and I found a good api for that).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on crypto.stackexchange.com. A good question, but doesn't belong here.

Comment: @Thorgal this course goes into the fundamentals of crypto and gives you an understanding of the basic building blocks. You need basic linalg, but it should be fine for a high school student: https://www.coursera.org/learn/crypto

Comment: t.m.adam -> You are right, but I have nearly finished my program so I'm going to need a code review so I hesitate to create or edit this topic.

Comment: user3080953 -> Thank you very much for the link ! <3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A relevant anecdote from Bruce Schneier:

See https://www.schneier.com/crypto-gram/archives/1998/1015.html#cipherdesign

> A cryptographer friend tells the story of an amateur who kept
>   bothering him with the cipher he invented. The cryptographer would
>   break the cipher, the amateur would make a change to "fix" it, and the
>   cryptographer would break it again. This exchange went on a few times
>   until the cryptographer became fed up. When the amateur visited him to
>   hear what the cryptographer thought, the cryptographer put three
>   envelopes face down on the table. "In each of these envelopes is an
>   attack against your cipher. Take one and read it. Don't come back
>   until you've discovered the other two attacks." The amateur was never
>   heard from again.

Use AES.

Comment: did not know this story, it's pretty funny. But my goal is not to use symmetric encryption but to create one. Will it be useful for humanity? I do not think so: as you know, AES is already responding to this need, but developing my own algorithm, even if I do not succeed, is useful to me. That's right: what do I have to lose? I am 15 years old and therefore have a lot of time to lose, so much to have fun hoping to create something. On the other hand, I strongly agree with you if you think it is a waste of time to try to create your own algorithm only to answer a need already answered by aes.

Comment: Well @Thorgal, this is a pretty good thing to be doing in your spare time -- way better than Fortnite, anyway :)   If you want to ask a question about your algorithm, though, "is it safe?" is the wrong one, because you know the answer is "no".   As Bruce implies, if you want to challenge yourself, it's better to focus on breaking simple ciphers instead of making them.   I also highly recommend his Book: https://www.schneier.com/books/applied_cryptography/   You will learn all kinds of amazing things you can actually use.

Comment: A friend just told me exactly the same thing about cracking ciphers. xD I will buy this book the next time I buy a thing on amazon it will help me to revise my English (I'm french), thank you very much for having devoted a little time to me. =)